# Can't connect to mongodb from webservice

Tags: java, android, web-services, mongodb, tomcat

I've created an Android app which sends SOAP requests to my Tomcat web server.
The web server has a web-service (MongoService.wsdl) that calls another class (DataLayer.java) which has a static method (getConnection) that tries to initialize the MongClient class (new MongoClient), but fails with no exception thrown.

When i ran this function from a java application it works perfectly.

The method:

```
/**Utility to Get the Connection from the database*/
    public static DBCollection getConnection(String dbName, String collectionName)throws UnknownHostException {

        MongoClient mongo = null;
        try {
            mongo = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            /**Gets database, incase if the database is not existing
                 MongoDB Creates it for you*/
            DB db = mongo.getDB(dbName);

            /**Gets collection / table from database specified if
                 collection doesn't exists, MongoDB will create it for
                 you*/
            DBCollection table = db.getCollection(collectionName);
            return table;
        }
```

Logcat:

> 09-24 23:23:14.223: W/System.err(18551): SoapFault - faultcode:
>   'soapenv:Server.userException' faultstring:
>   'java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException' faultactor: 'null'
>   detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@42d023c8 09-24 23:23:14.223:
>   W/System.err(18551):  at
>   org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.parseBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:112)
>   09-24 23:23:14.223: W/System.err(18551):  at
>   org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:137) 09-24
>   23:23:14.223: W/System.err(18551):    at
>   org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:63) 09-24
>   23:23:14.223: W/System.err(18551):    at
>   org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:100)
>   09-24 23:23:14.223: W/System.err(18551):  at
>   com.example.myfirstapp.WebService.invokeHelloWorldWS(WebService.java:51)
>   09-24 23:23:14.223: W/System.err(18551):  at
>   com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity$AsyncCallWS.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:251)
>   09-24 23:23:14.223: W/System.err(18551):  at
>   com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity$AsyncCallWS.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
>   09-24 23:23:14.223: W/System.err(18551):  at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288) 09-24 23:23:14.223:
>   W/System.err(18551):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 09-24
>   23:23:14.223: W/System.err(18551):    at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 09-24
>   23:23:14.223: W/System.err(18551):    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>   09-24 23:23:14.223: W/System.err(18551):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>   09-24 23:23:14.223: W/System.err(18551):  at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841) 09-24 23:23:14.233:
>   I/dalvikvm(18551): Jit: resizing JitTable from 4096 to 8192 09-24
>   23:23:55.967: D/dalvikvm(18551): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3538K, 19% free
>   16265K/20064K, paused 49ms, total 49ms

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue adding the mongo-driver.jar to the WEB-INF/lib folder. If using eclipse and maven, it can be solved adding the maven dependencies to the "Deployment Assembly" in the project properties.